# Clearing a matlibplot from a Tkinter GUI

Tags: json, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter, canvas

---

The image shows the GUI:
[image]

1. I am making a GUI with Tkinter which can show graphs which have been plotted with matplotlib.
2. The graphs get their x and y values from a JSON file.
3. The data from the JSON file gets collected by some code which I wrote (this code is included in the code below)

What works: The collecting of data from the JSON-file, plotting the data in a graph via matplotlib, and showing this graph on a tkinter canvas all works fine.

Problem: I cannot clear the canvas, such that I can display another graph based on data from another JSON file. I have to close the program, start it again, and select a different JSON file, if I want to see another graph.

Here is the code:

```
################################### GUI program for graphs #######################################

##### Scrollbar for the listbox #####
Myframe = Frame(inspect_data)
Myframe.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=Y)
my_scrollbar = Scrollbar(Myframe, orient=VERTICAL)

#####Listbox#####
vores_listebox = Listbox(Myframe, width=22, height=40,
                         yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
vores_listebox.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True)

my_scrollbar.config(command=vores_listebox.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
Myframe.pack()


###### Button functions ######
path_us = ""


def vis_NS():
    vores_listebox.delete(0, END)
    # Husk at ændre mapper##
    global path_us
    path_us = "C://Users//canal//OneDrive//Dokumenter//AAU//3. semester//1//"
    for x in os.listdir(path_us):
        if x.endswith(".json"):
            vores_listebox.insert(END, x)


def vis_OS():
    global path_us
    path_us = "C://Users//canal//OneDrive//Dokumenter//AAU//3. semester//2//"
    vores_listebox.delete(0, END)
    # De NS;OS,US,MS skal ligge i hver sin mappe#
    for x in os.listdir(path_us):
        if x.endswith(".json"):
            vores_listebox.insert(END, x)


def vis_US():
    vores_listebox.delete(0, END)
    for x in os.listdir("C://Users//canal//OneDrive//Dokumenter//AAU//3. semester//2"):
        if x.endswith(".json"):
            vores_listebox.insert(END, x)


def vis_MS():
    vores_listebox.delete(0, END)
    for x in os.listdir("C://Users//canal//OneDrive//Dokumenter//AAU//3. semester//2"):
        if x.endswith(".json"):
            vores_listebox.insert(END, x)


#### Buttons #####
button1 = Button(inspect_data,
                 text="Normal screwing",
                 width=17,
                 height=2,
                 bg="white",
                 fg="black",
                 command=vis_NS
                 )
button1.place(x=5, y=10)

button2 = Button(inspect_data,
                 text="Over screwing",
                 width=17,
                 height=2,
                 bg="white",
                 fg="black",
                 command=vis_OS
                 )
button2.place(x=5, y=50)

button3 = Button(inspect_data,
                 text="Under screwing",
                 width=17,
                 height=2,
                 bg="white",
                 fg="black",
                 command=vis_US
                 )
button3.place(x=5, y=90)

button4 = Button(inspect_data,
                 text="Missing screw",
                 width=17,
                 height=2,
                 bg="white",
                 fg="black",
                 command=vis_MS
                 )
button4.place(x=5, y=130)

######en fil bliver trykket#####

# placing the canvas on the Tkinter window


def items_selected(event):
    selected_indices = vores_listebox.curselection()

    selected_json = ",".join([vores_listebox.get(i) for i in selected_indices])
    full_file_path = path_us + selected_json
    open_json = js.load(open(full_file_path, "r"))
    time = [open_json['XML_Data']
            ['Wsk3Vectors']['X_Axis']['Values']['float']]
    rpm = [open_json['XML_Data']['Wsk3Vectors']
           ['Y_AxesList']['AxisData'][0]['Values']['float']]
    torque = [open_json['XML_Data']['Wsk3Vectors']
              ['Y_AxesList']['AxisData'][1]['Values']['float']]
    current = [open_json['XML_Data']['Wsk3Vectors']
               ['Y_AxesList']['AxisData'][2]['Values']['float']]
    angle = [open_json['XML_Data']['Wsk3Vectors']
             ['Y_AxesList']['AxisData'][3]['Values']['float']]
    depth = [open_json['XML_Data']['Wsk3Vectors']
             ['Y_AxesList']['AxisData'][4]['Values']['float']]


####### Using Matlib.pyplot to plot 5 graphs #######
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (7, 10)

    plt.subplot(5, 1, 1)
    plt.scatter(time, rpm, c="b", linewidths=2,
                marker=",", edgecolor="b", s=1, alpha=0.5)
    plt.title(selected_json)
    plt.gca().axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    plt.ylabel("RPM")
    plt.grid()

    plt.subplot(5, 1, 2)
    plt.scatter(time, torque, c="g", linewidths=1,
                marker=",", edgecolor="g", s=1, alpha=0.3)
    plt.gca().axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    plt.ylabel("Torque [Nm]")
    plt.grid()

    plt.subplot(5, 1, 3)
    plt.scatter(time, current, c="r", linewidths=2,
                marker=",", edgecolor="r", s=1, alpha=0.5)
    plt.gca().axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    plt.ylabel("Current [Amps]")
    plt.grid()

    plt.subplot(5, 1, 4)
    plt.scatter(time, angle, c="m", linewidths=2,
                marker=",", edgecolor="m", s=1, alpha=0.5)
    plt.gca().axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    plt.ylabel("Angle [RAD]")
    plt.grid()

    plt.subplot(5, 1, 5)
    plt.scatter(time, depth, c="c", linewidths=2,
                marker=",", edgecolor="c", s=1, alpha=0.5)
    plt.xlabel("Time [ms]")
    plt.ylabel("Depth [mm]")
    plt.grid()

    #### Sowing all the subplots in a tkinter canvas ########

    fig = plt.figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=inspect_data)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    # toolbar = matplotlib.NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(
    #    canvas, self)
    # toolbar.update()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


vores_listebox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', items_selected)

root.after(1000, converter)
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried canvas.delete(all), plt.clf() among other things. One solution I think could work is:

If I start the function def items_selected to clear the figure inside the canvas by using: plt.clf(fig), however "fig" is not defined at this point, so python wouldn't know what this means.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that the problem originates from plotting to plt, and not directly onto some axis from a figure linked to tkinter. Try to bind your subplot figure directly to your canvas outside the items_selected() function, and then redraw the canvas whenever you change the underlying matplotlib figure:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 1, figsize=(7, 10))
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, inspect_data)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

def items_selected(event):
    .....
    axes[0].scatter(time, rpm, c="b", linewidths=2,
                marker=",", edgecolor="b", s=1, alpha=0.5)
    axes[0].set_title(selected_json)
    axes[0].set_xticklabels([])
    axes[0].set_ylabel("RPM")
    axes[0].grid()
    .... 
   
    canvas.draw()
```

Comment: I tried, but with no succes. I have now resorted to using plt.show(), which works fine. But this always displays a small window which i have to manually resize to my liking.